# Fetch SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, fetch

hey guys im having some wierd issue,
i get the error i stated in the title when i try to fetch something from an api,
when i check with postman with the same url i get a valid jason,

the request comes back with a status of 200 so its fine on that end.

howerver when i execute the following command the error occurs:

```
fetch('/api/bug',{mode:'no-cors'}).then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

the Json:

{
    "_id" : "abc123",
    "title" : "Cannot save ",
    "description" : "problem ",
    "severity" : 1,
    "createdAt" : 154210735954,
    "creator" : {"nickname" : "Nick"}
   }

Edit:
After changing from Json To Text,

The fetch request returns the html of the page, and the postman request return a json, any reason for this?

Comment: Try to print out `response.text()` instead of parsing as JSON, there are very good chances that - regardless the HTTP status code - server returned an HTML error page.

Comment: just checked, i get the index.html back for some reason, why in postman i get the json and here i get the page html?